# RewriteRule For Matching Arbitrary PHP Files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm somewhat new to `htaccess` rewrite rules, and have been scratching my head for the past few days on what's happening here. No amount of Googling seemed to help, so hopefully somebody knows the answer.

I have a site that can be accessed as:

```
www.site.com
www.site.com/684
www.site.com/684/some-slug-name-here
```

All of these scenarios should go to `index.php` and pass in the optional `id=684` and `slug=some-slug-name-here`

Which works fine.

My problem is I have a separate file. Right now it's called `admintagger.php` - but this fails when I call it anything. `21g12fjhg2349yf234f.php` has the same issue.

The problem is that that I would like to be able to access `admintagger.php` from `www.site.com/admintagger`

but it seems to be matching my rule for index, and taking me there instead.

Here is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^imagetagger$ /imagetagger.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?(.*)?/?$ index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Good question. Could you make its title more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to arbitrarily be able to access php files via the name (sans extension) then you need to create a general rule for it. But you need to be careful otherwise you may be rewriting legitimate requests for existing resources (like a directory, or a slug). Try this instead:

```
# make sure we aren't clobbering legit requests:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# see if appending a ".php" to the end of the request will map to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# internally rewrite to include the .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Then you can have your routing to index.php right after that:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?(.*)?/?$ index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Although you may be better off create a separate rule for each of your 3 cases:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Yep, that solved everything. I'm pretty well versed in PHP but these RewriteRules still escape me :( Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @user1745715 as far as well formed languages go, mod_rewrite is retarded and unpredictable. It's one of those things that has so many weird nuances that you'll never get used to it until you fail a bunch of times.